# Выбор физического 2D-движка на C++

Tags: разработка-игр, движок, c++

Вообщем пытаюсь написать игру, нужен бесплатный, на C++, исключительно физический 2d движок, не надо, чтобы он мог музыку играть, тени рисовать и т.д. Нужен только исключительно просчет физики. Приветствуется "простота" движка. Box2d не советуйте, с ним у меня ничего не получилось...

Comment: Боюсь, что проще, чем `Box2D,` вы вряд ли что-то найдете. Разве что какую-нибудь студенческую поделку, с которой проблем будет еще больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) есть десяток 2D движков. Просчет 2D физики не так то и сложно реализовать, чтобы делать его на какой-то чужой библиотеке.

Например я использую в своем движке систему частиц + идеи [SPH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics)(им можно делать не только воду) + [Spatial Hashing](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~jmesit/publications/scsc%202005.pdf).

Хотя 2D физика это слишком общее понятие, что вам нужно конкретно? Веревки? Кинематические пары? Пружины? Маятники? Гравитация? Упругие столкновения? Что-то на подобии Angry Birds?

Тот вариант что я предложил хорошо подходит для имитации системы из большого количества однотипных объектов вроде воды, космоса, песка, взрывов, снега, крови и используется в 95% случаев.

Еще при программировании сложной модели стоит придерживаться той идеи, что любая механическая система полностью описывается [функцией Лагранжа](http://www.twirpx.com/file/18039/). При должном умении таким способом можно запрограммировать вообще что угодно. Естественно с поправкой на возможность быстрого численного решения соответствующих дифуров. Но это чисто теоретическое решение в лоб, обычно подбирают какую-нибудь упрощенную модель.

```
L(t,q1,q1',q2,q2'...qi,qi'), где t - время, qi - iая обобщенная координата, qi' - скорость изменения iой обощенной координаты(производная)
```

Comment: Заинтересовался движком Allegro, но нигде его не нашел.... Он что подпольный?))) Не знаете где его можно скачать?

Comment: http://alleg.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: @Alerr То есть `Box2D` вам показался сложным, и вы полагаете, что  вникнуть в `Allegro` с его `int al_ustr_find_cset_cstr(const ALLEGRO_USTR *us, int start_pos, const char *reject)` будет проще?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Он там первый в списке просто.
@Aller Это не физический движок похоже. Читайте мануал. http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.7/

Comment: Я не знаю, хочу посмотреть что за штука.... Проблема с box2d в том, что не понятно по какой причине, при совмещении box и других библиотек вылазиют ошибки времени исполнения.... +у них там мануал не понятно как написан... Пишут к примеру движек быстрее чем мануалы к нему.... В последней версии бокса 2.2.1 ничего не смог сделать, даже мир создать, т.к. его функции сильно отличаются по принимаемым аргументам от мануальных.... Может кто-нибудь скинуть простой пример создания мира(консольный)????

Comment: @Alerr Сначала четко определитесь чего вы хотите сделать, потом подбирайте движок. С box2d не работал поэтому ничего не могу сказать на эту тему. У меня свой он интегрирован в игру и поэтому там не нужно создавать никакой еще один лишний уровень абстракции вроде мира. Покидаю тред. Удачи.

Comment: Allegro как вариант отпал...

Comment: Спасибо igumnov.